# Expiration time in php cookie doesn't work

Tags: php, cookies

I have a declaration like this:

```
setcookie("cookieName", "cookieValue", time() + (3600 * 24 * 2));
```

When I take a look on Google Chrome the Expiration time its 30 minutes ago!
And in Firefox its now + 30 minutes...

I can't understand this weird behaviour.

Someone can help me please?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Works fine for me it's set for 2 days, please show us the full script and tell us which chrome and firefox version you use

Comment: basic debugging: check what time chrome and firefox think it is on your system, and check what's actually coming out of PHP (e.g. http inspector and see what the cookie header really looks like).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, its my fault.

I haven't see that setcookie is called after headers have been sent.

Thanks!